# How to use a positional vector to create a binary string?

Tags: r, vector, position

I have a vector `c(2, 5)` and I want to turn this into a vector of *n* elements where positions 2 and 5 are equal to 1 and any remaining positions are equal to zero.

i.e. If I want to create a vector of length 6, I would want to use vector `c(2, 5)` to generate the following vector:

`c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0)`

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
x <- c(2, 5)
n <- 6
replace(integer(n), x, 1L)
# [1] 0 1 0 0 1 0
```

And another option is

```
as.integer(1:n %in% x)
# [1] 0 1 0 0 1 0
```

Comment: I'm amazed I've worked so long with `switch` and `ifelse` and did not get exposed to (or comfortable with) `replace` and `recode` until well into my R-learning. Do you know of "gotchas" with `replace` as opposed to `ifelse`? (They are not perfectly interchangeable, I realize.)

Comment: @r2evans - I haven't run across any yet.  It's a really simple replacement function (see the source), and it even works on lists.

Comment: That's what I was hoping ... I've run into many situations where `ifelse` doesn't do what I expect, and though it's rather simple too, I think `replace` may be more straight-forward. (I also recall cautions against using `ifelse`, but I can't think of them off the top of my head.)

Comment: @RichScriven, I'm in the same boat as r2evans as I haven't been exposed to `replace` before. After looking at the source for the function, I removed my solution as it is pretty much the same. I honestly had no idea. I'm guessing the slightly slower timing is attributed to the extra function call overhead. Thanks per usual for your enlightening answers.